# Confidence Interval for Predictions Made by Sklearn LassoCV Regression Model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels, confidence-interval

I have a data set "`X`" with "`n`" samples, which was used for training a lasso regression model.
There were "`p`" predictors in the dataset from which the LassoCV selected "`k`" of them in the final trained model. I will use this model to make predictions.
I want to know the Confidence Interval for my predictions done by this model.

Assuming "`y`" are the true lables for my data, and "`y^`" are the predicted values by my model, and **90%** of confidence to be of interest, the following formula was used:

```
conf_int = 1.645 * (np.sqrt(sum((y - y^)**2)/(n - k - 2)))
```

I was wondering if this formula is correct. If not, I appreciate it if you could provide me with some link or tutorial for that.

Thanks in advance for your opinions and comments